# How to show one div in iframe without using jquery angular

Tags: html, angular, iframe, scroll

I'm using iframe to display content of remote website that's not my own. I want to show only one specific div from that website but the only solution I'm finding is the one with jquery. Is there any way to scroll to that div or get that div using only angular or javascript?

I tried accessing iframe body but I;m getting null as a  result and a 'Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4400" from accessing a cross-origin frame' error.

```
  @ViewChild('iframe', { static: true }) iframe: ElementRef;

 getBody(): void {
    console.log(this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.document.body);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't be able to access the contents of the iframe from the parent, except when the external website explicitly allows that (with the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header). How would you do it in jquery?

Comment: @gitaarik this is the solution someone wrote '$('#target-div').load('http://www.example.com/website.php #wanted-section');'

Comment: Did you try it? It might be that this worked in the time that this limitation of accessing iframe contents was not yet implemented. It was implemented because of security reasons.

Comment: I didn't try it tho. I don't use jquery in my project.

Comment: So if you would try it, it would probably give the same error.